# Wordpress gallery not sorting the images if I change the order of image ids

Tags: gallery

I am using Wordpress gallery in a theme.

I am trying to change the order of images by changing the order of ids but it is not working for me. I have searched relative questions to wordpress gallery but nothing is working for me.

I also have deactive all the plugins.
I also do not have install any post type order plugin in my theme.

The short code for the galleries are

```
 [gallery columns="4" ids="310,309,311,312,315,314,313"]

[gallery columns="4" ids="309,310,311,312,315,314,313"]
```

But the result is same for both the short code. [here](http://www.aerozproducts.com/fuelscoop/fuelscoop-2/gallery-hino-fuelscoop/)

Please suggest me how to sort the images by ids.

Answer (score 3):

Add `order` and/or `orderby` parameters to your shortcode. For example:

```
[gallery columns="4" ids="310,309,311,312,315,314,313" order="DESC" orderby="ID"]
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode#Options

Comment: Sorry to say but its not working for me. I have already tried it. I think there is some code in my theme which is forcefully ordering the post. Can you tell me what could be that code so that I can search that in my theme.

Comment: ok I found the code. It was a hook of add_filter to 'posts_orderby'  and function was using global $wpdb. I removed it and now working for me.

Comment: How could I have possibly told you what code in your theme, which you haven't named and which is one of hundreds or thousands of themes, was causing the problem?

Comment: Agreed, I have solved the problem. I asked because i also was not aware what would be the code, I hoped an expert will have knowledge about what code can cause the problem.

Comment: There are probably a dozen ways to break a gallery. That is the problem with guessing without seeing the code.

Comment: ok ......agreed

Comment: I think you mixed it with the "include" parameter. With "include" you can using orderby. Using "ids"  you should be able to the order on your own.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where the images **did not display in the correct order** in admin but **did display in the correct order on the front end**. After many many, many hours of research and pulling my hair out! I stumbled on this post. I then hunted through a very customized function file where I found a filter that captured all ajax calls and ordered by ID! As soon as I removed this filter the gallery displayed in the correct order!

For those who are interested the filter was `add_filter('ajax_query_attachments_args', ' ----------- ');`